# How can I use the Single Developer Licence or Project License to an application?

Tags: jxbrowser

If I buy an Single Developer Licence, Can I put the license in other jar,While other developer will user the jar to show some web content in my swing application?

Can I distribute my swing application for my customer to use? Can the persion who use the swing application open a website in the application?

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to integration or any development work. It is the licensing policy question and all the information is available in JxBrowser Product License Agreement: https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/licence-agreement